# PHP regex get only first value in between two strings

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that looks like this

**aa** bcdef123efg **hh aa** lklmasd456 **hh**
(whitespace and bolding is used for illustration)

If I have `456`, I want to find where `456` is and grab everything in between **aa** and **hh**.

This is the regex that I was able to come up with so far `(?=aa)(.*)456(.*)(?=hh)`

However, that doesn't stop at the first occurance of aa it encounters (backwards from the 456 match)

What would be the proper syntax for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: `/aa(.*?456.*?)hh/`?

Comment: so given your string, what is the expected match?

Comment: Are you just trying to extract the string between aa and hh? Is it always hhaa or are there characters between them? If not, what about exploding them into an array and using inarray() to find strings with '456'?

Comment: @MarcB `aa(.*?456.*?)hh` won't stop at first `hh`

Comment: @anubhava: the ungreedy .*? should allow for that.

Comment: See `aa(.*?456.*?)hh` [not working here](http://regex101.com/r/oQ6yP2/2)

Comment: Marc's solution didn't work. Exploding will work, but it's way too slow and resource intensive when doing this up to 1000 times.

Comment: How many words can occur between **aa** and the word containing 456? `aa \w+456\w* hh` will work if there are no arbitrary number of other words in-between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookaround based regex:

```
aa((?:(?!hh).)*?456(?:(?!hh).)*?)hh
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oQ6yP2/1)